# Is Nothing equal to Default?

Tags: vb.net

What happens when i set a variable to nothing in VB.NET?
Is it true that nothing equals to default, or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's a value type (like Integer, Double, etc.) setting the variable to Nothing will set it to the default value.

If it's a reference type, it will really be set to Nothing (null value).

In [Microsoft's words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx):

> Assigning Nothing to a variable sets
>   it to the default value for its
>   declared type.
>
> If the variable is of a reference
>   type, a value of Nothing means that
>   the variable is not associated with
>   any object. The variable has a null
>   value.

Answer (score 2):

What can really bite you with this is that if you have a construct like this in C#

```
int? result = (a != null ? a.b : (int?)null);
```

and you replace it with the following VB (which does compile)

```
Dim result As Integer? = If(a IsNot Nothing, a.b, Nothing)
```

What will result be?

The answer is that it will be 0, not null.

Answer (score 1):

It equals default on ValueTypes or Structs, and is equal to null on Object types.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming VB.NET is largely similar to C#, `null`, which is called `Nothing` in VB.NET means that a reference doesn't point to anything. All types have default values when they are declared but not assigned: for example, the default value for `int`s is `0`. The default value for reference types is the null value `Nothing`. So an unassigned variable of a reference type will have the value `Nothing` (null).

Answer (score 0):

There's good blog Article on [Null vs Nothing](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/30/a-whole-lot-of-nothing/) by Eric Lippert

Nothing does not equal default in all cases.

Comment: -1. It's a great article but it's about **VBScript** and the question is about **Visual Basic.Net**. They behave completely differently - VBScript only has `Variants` not strongly typed variables.

Comment: @Mark: and yet the answer is the same wither it's VB.Net or VBScript.

Comment: The link isn't working for me.  Try http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/30/53120.aspx