# Dim intResult As Integer = Nothing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

VB.NET compiles:

```
Dim intResult As Integer = Nothing
```

C# does not:

```
int intResult = null; // cannot convert
```

How the result finally goes to MSIL?

More that than, VB code is OK:

```
If intResult > Nothing Then
```

EDIT

OK, MS [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx):

> Assigning Nothing to a variable sets it to the default value for its declared type.

But it tells nothing about `Nothing` **comparation**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Nothing` in VB.NET is actually equivalent to `default(Type)` in C#.

So `int intResult = default(int);` is the C# equivalent.

According to the [VB.NET Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx): "Assigning Nothing to a variable sets it to the default value for its declared type. If that type contains variable members, they are all set to their default values."

---

**Edit:** Regarding the comparison to `Nothing`: 
I'm guessing `intResult > Nothing` is interpreted as `intResult > 0`, because the compile-time type of `intResult` is `Integer`, which has a default value of 0.  If the type of intResult is not known at compile time (e.g., it is a boxed `Integer`), I suspect that this would not compile.

See the [Community Content section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx#CommunityContent) at the bottom of the VB.NET Language Reference page for a similar example (`Nothing < 2`).

Comment: Also, the int type in C# cannot be null.

Comment: +1 - see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976112/is-nothing-equal-to-default

Comment: +1: Nice. I don't know VB.NET; I half-expected the answer to be that the compiler would change the variable declaration to `Nullable<int>` and initialize it to `null`.

Comment: OK, now about **assignment** I understood, but how does it **compare** int to Nothing now? At least, this is not documented.

Comment: I agree with the community content section notice: **It's worth mentioning**

Answer (score 0):

Ints are not nullable in c# simple as that.  If you want to you can use `System.Nullable<int>` short for whinch is

`int? result = null`.

Comment: I know, thanks, the question is not about nullable types, but how does VB.NET permits to a non-nullable type be nullable, and compare Nothing to int...